# How do I run disk cleanup for system files on C Drive in the Powershell command line?

Tags: powershell

The title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to create a policy for an assortment of devices being monitored. I want to, specifically, run the disk cleanup that you can find in a drive's properties window.

[image: Windows C Drive Properties]

I'd want it to also check the system files for anything that can be deleted like you can after disk cleanup finishes scanning the drive.

[image: Disk Cleanup C Drive]

I'm not terribly familiar with commands for the powershell command line (the program I'm using to create the policy, however, uses it specifically) so please be kind and explain as you would to a beginner. Also, if what I want to do simply isn't possible, please let me know. As you can imagine, I'm not terribly versed in what is or isn't possible with Powershell.

Comment: https://winaero.com/cleanmgr-exe-command-line-arguments-in-windows-10/

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-WindowsDiskCleanup/1.1/Content/Invoke-WindowsDiskCleanup.ps1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### cleanmgr.exe

You're wanting to use [cleanmgr.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cleanmgr) and one of it's [many switches.](https://ss64.com/nt/cleanmgr.html#:%7E:text=CLEANMGR.exe,%2C%20downloaded%20files%2C%20recycle%20bin.&text=If%20CLEANMGR%20is%20run%20without,the%20process%20slower%20to%20startup.)

You can do something like `cleanmgr.exe /SAGESET:number` or `cleanmgr.exe /verylowdisk`

### /sageset

This switch `/sageset` displays the Disk Cleanup Settings dialog box and creates a registry key to store the settings. The number denotes the settings which will be stored in the Registry when your run `/sagerun` switch later on – and basically lets you make shortcuts to different stored configurations or schedule automatic cleanup in the Task Scheduler.

In effect the `/sagerun:n` switch will run the specified tasks that are assigned to the `n` value by [using the `/sageset` switch.](https://carlwebster.com/set-sageset1-powershell-script-v1-00/)

Comment: Funny enough, I was already aware of cleanmgr.exe as well as the /verylowdiskspace flag. I, however, did not know what it specifically did. I'm guessing it goes through the system files as well?

Comment: that blue button that you circled? opens cleanmgr.exe :) "disk cleanup" == cleanmgr.exe.

Comment: Huh, I was under the impression that it only did the first wave of scans and not the second to also scan system files. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK `sageset:` allows you get set the files you want and `sagerun:` processes the actual cleaning.